# Rails rake db:migration do not recognise new migrates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-activerecord, database-migration

strange problem with rails migration.

I have 2 migrations in my app
[image]

I run rake db:migrate
[image]

Only one migration executed. No matter how many time I tried, the second migration was ignored

I also tried to run the specific migration by specifying a version number, but no luck[image]

---

Use rails 4.1
The first migration generated by

```
rails g scaffold User .......
```

The second migration generated by devise plugin

```
rails g devise user ........
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The migration file generated is without extension `.rb`. 
It was an issue that was already reported in Devise. It was resolved in `Devise version 3.2.3`. Read the issue **[Generated migration filename missing extension #2971](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2971)**

Answer (score 3):

Second file needs the .rb extension?

Comment: Yes, you are correct! solved it. very strange however. I never generate migrations manually. The devise gem produced the migration without ".rb" extension. Could it be a bug of the gem?

Comment: @GingerJim yep, it seems Kirti has found the the [issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2971) below :)